# Consul on google cloud machine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, consul

I run consul on google cloud, but I cannot get access to consul via http.

I start it like this:

```
./consul agent -server -bootstrap-expect=1 -data-dir=consul-data -ui
```

It start okey, but I cannot get access to the consul using outer IP http://35.228.60.122:8500

But if I run http server on machine

```
python3 -m http.server 8080
```

Everything is ok and I can get access to it. What is the problem with consul?

I also tryed to allow all ports

[image]

Comment: Did you open port 8500/8501/8600 etc in the VPC firewall? Review the required ports for Consul: https://www.consul.io/docs/install/ports Read about Consul security before opening ports.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the HTTP address to listen on a public IP (Port 8500). By default it uses loopback. The -client flag does this, but also changes the IP of all the listeners (RPC, HTTP, DNS). You can do more fine grained configuration with a configuration file however.